# What kind of sentence structure it is? I mean Gandhian it

Tags: nominalization

It is not surprising that terrorists struck Bacha Khan University on the death anniversary of the Gandhian it is named after......

Gandhian is - related to mahatma ghandi

Comment: It is not surprising that terrorists struck Bacha Khan University on the death anniversary of the relative of Gandhi that it is named after....

Comment: It is not surprising that terrorists struck Bacha Khan University on the death anniversary of the Gandhian (that) it is named after - it's called a relative clause

Comment: Buy here no that is used

Comment: I don't think many native speakers would accept this use of *Ghandian*. Consider *Dickensian, Shavian, Marxist, Trotskyite*, for example. When such derivations from proper names are used as *nouns*, they only ever identify someone who actively endorses whatever the original is famous for, not just someone who happens to be a relative sharing the same surname.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Bacha Khan was his friends and ideologi follower ....

Comment: 'That' is often deleted (omitted) from that-clauses. It's fine doing that here; omitting the first one (It is not surprising _that_ terrorists struck Bacha Khan University on the death anniversary of the relative of Ghandi it is named after) would leave a clumsy, unwieldy remnant and so is not advisable.

Comment: Manish: sorry - I was misled by Edwin's comment. But I'll leave mine there, since although *your* usage is okay, it wouldn't have been if Edwin's interpretation had been correct.

Comment: We look Gandhian as noun or adjective @FumbleFingers

Answer (score 2):

Gandhian, is actually an adjective. But it is used as a **noun** here.

[Merriam-Webster editor Neil Serven gives us an explanation](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/adjectives-used-as-nouns)

> For example, the words *poor* and *sick* are easily recognizable as adjectives:
>
> We were too *poor* to afford a car.
>
> He was *sick* with a head cold.
>
> As with most adjectives, *poor* and *sick* can be used before a noun to modify that noun:
>
> *poor* artists
>
> a *sick* patient
>
> But what happens when such an adjective is preceded by *the* but not followed by a noun?
>
> She gives money to the *poor*.
>
> Nurses care for the *sick*.
>
> The words *poor* and *sick* here are used to refer to poor people and sick people, respectively, with the nouns they modify omitted.
>
> While they function like nouns here, they are not defined as nouns because they do not meet any of the other criteria that typically distinguishes a word as a *noun*.

[Bacha Khan](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khan_Abdul_Ghaffar_Khan) was a Pakistani independence activist who followed the basic principles of Gandhiism. He was also a close friend of [Gandhi](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahatma_Gandhi)

Also see [Bacha Khan University](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bacha_Khan_University), which was named after him.

[Gandhian](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/gandhian) (*adjective*) is someone related to Gandhi or Gandhiism.

[Gandhiism](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/gandhiism)  is a body of ideas and principles that describes the inspiration, vision and the life work of Mohandas Gandhi. It is particularly associated with his contributions to the idea of nonviolent resistance, sometimes also called civil resistance.

Comment: Gandhian it  adjectives +it?

Comment: We look Gandhian as a noun or adjective

Comment: It may be that you are not clear on the meaning of *adjective*; "Gandhian" alone could be one, but "a/the Gandhian" grammatically cannot.

Answer (score -1):

The journalist here is using *Gandhian* not in its usual adjectival sense, but as a noun meaning 'a member of the Gandhi clan'.  Such terms were used in classical times, when an *Alcmeonid* or * *the Atreides* would be related to an important family but not necessarily bearing the family name; they are scarcely used nowadays (unless some Indian English speaker knows otherwise?) and *the Gandhi it was named for* would be more usual.

*No, in Aeschylus, not the Herbert tribute.